# Python: Permutations of 3 Elements

Tags: python, list, combinations, permutation

How do you find all permutations of a list with 3 elements in Python?

For example, input

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

would return

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
```

Thanks!

Comment: try looking at `itertools.permutations`

Comment: Literally the first thing that popped up in a google search. Please do some research before asking a question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python

Comment: OP wanted combinations not permutations like he said, so, he was confused and needed help. I absolutely think this was a question for this site.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [list(x) for x in combinations(lst, 3)]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
>>>
```

---

Regarding your comment, you would make that list of strings by adding in [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)*:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [''.join(map(str, x)) for x in combinations(lst, 3)]
['123', '124', '134', '234']
>>>
```

---

**Note:*  You need to do `map(str, x)` because `str.join` requires an iterable of strings.

Comment: How would you do it as a string, like return ['123', '124', '134', '234']